# Physical Address to GeoLocation UK

Tags: geolocation, street-address, postal-code

Is there a good physical address to GeoLocation conversion database in the UK? I am trying to use this to build a globrix style search box http://www.globrix.com/ for a web application. Any pointers will be nice. I have been searching for hours. I have found several that convert UK Postcodes into Geolocation. But I need the addresses listed as on Globrix.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Google Maps API provides a geocoder webservice that you can actually use independently of Google Maps itself. You send it the address/postcode, and it responds with a lat/long plus disambiguated addresses. We use it server-side in the UK to do address lookup. It's incredibly quick, too.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html

Comment: The Google Maps API is the next step.. What I need to start with is a mechanism to list all the addresses and display using AJAX like on Globrix first.

Comment: Coooooool Stuff.. This does not give me the AJAX style popup a 100% but is good enough for me to work with..

Comment: "The Google Maps API provides a geocoder webservice that you can actually use independently of Google Maps itself." Guess that depends on whether you mean it's possible to use it independently, or legal to use it independently. Currently the web page you've linked to specifies, "Note: the Geocoding API may only be used in conjunction with a Google map; geocoding results without displaying them on a map is prohibited. For complete details on allowed usage, consult the Maps API Terms of Service License Restrictions."

Answer (score 1):

http://www.postcodeanywhere.co.uk should be able to help with this. Alternatively, you can buy the "PAF" (Postcode Address File) from the Royal Mail, but it is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Update for information relating UK geolocations in 2020. Since 2009:

- Google's Geocoder has gotten an order of magnitude more expensive in 2018. It's ~0.5c per search with no free tier
- Office for National Statistics have released a free postcode directory called ONSPD. This means if you have the postcode of your address, you can resolve a geolocation accurate to the postcode centroid (this may be 10-100m or so out). There's a free public service API available at https://postcodes.io which allows you to forward or reverse geocode a postcode. There are also public docker data and application images which allow you to host this easily
- If you're interested in Rooftop accurate geocodes, a change in Ordnance Survey licensing in 2020 has meant its much simpler and cheaper to access geolocations for almost every premise in Great Britain from Ordnance Survey by combining it with Royal Mail PAF (Postcode Address File). As of September 2020, I think https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk is currently the only company to offer complete and authoritative rooftop geolocations under these new rules. It's likely other PAF vendors will catch up over the coming years.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of postcodes.io and work for ideal-postcodes.co.uk